# Can Pandas DataFrame.sort_index() performance be improved on sorted data?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Is there any way to improve the performance of `DataFrame.sort_index()` when the data is already sorted by the columns that are used for the index? On a dataset with 40 mio records, `sort_index()` takes 3.25 mins for me, independent on whether the data is sorted already or not.

If there is no intended way high level way to do it, is there maybe a low level way of changing the `DataFrame` state to sorted by index without actually sorting it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you can verify that the index is sorted prior to actually sorting it with [`DataFrame.index.is_monotonic_increasing`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.is_monotonic.html), which should be faster. So you could do something like:

```
if not df.index.is_monotonic_increasing:
    df = df.sort_index()
```

Comment: Ha, thank you, after trying I figured that `is_lexsorted()` is aware of the sort state after reading the data. I somehow assumed that it wouldn't be, because if it is I would have expected `sort_index()` to be aware of it and not do anything on a pre-sorted index.